# Multiple audio tracks in m3u8 manifest file

Tags: audio, video-streaming, manifest, m3u8

I have this manifest file:

> ```
> #EXTM3U
> #EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-1",NAME="Audio",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio.m3u8"
> #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1758000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,AUDIO="audio-1"
> video_720p.m3u8
> #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=896000,RESOLUTION=640x480,AUDIO="audio-1"
> video_480p.m3u8
> ```

I want to add more audio tracks to it after it's creation.
Can I just add the at the end of the file. Like this?

> ```
> #EXTM3U
> #EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-1",NAME="Audio",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES,URI="audio.m3u8"
> #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1758000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,AUDIO="audio-1"
> video_720p.m3u8
> #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=896000,RESOLUTION=640x480,AUDIO="audio-1"
> video_480p.m3u8
> #EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-1",NAME="Audio2",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=NO,URI="audio2.m3u8"
> #EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-1",NAME="Audio3",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=NO,URI="audio3.m3u8"
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI, Yes, you can put more tracks at the end of the m3u8 file.